# MacBook Battery charging

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I recently bought a replacement battery for my MacBook battery. In Coconut Battery the Current charge has been as high as 8000 mah, yet the maximum capacity is listed as 6100. When the battery icon shows 100% has been reached the MagSafe light stays orange and doesn't turn green till the Current Charge exceeds the Maximum Charge.

Also, sometimes the laptop running on battery power will just shut off at 50%. When I plug in the charger it turns back on without a reboot but suddenly the battery icon shows 10 or 11 %..
Any ideas on these issues? Could my charger be defective and charging the battery too much?

Comment: Could you take a screen shot of your battery info in the About this Mac, more info, system report and publish it here.

Comment: Also reset your SMC and EFI just in case and while you are at it tell us about the battery? is it OEM ?

Comment: The battery charger can not charge to much, it works by pull mode, the battery pulls as much as it needs.

Comment: When I charge my laptop again I will post a screenshot. The battery is not OEM; I bought it from Amazon.

Comment: The not OEM battery might have different (Ω) ohmic resistance, leading to your problems. Where do you get the 8000mha from ? for the screen shot and the cycle count you do not have to wait till it is charged.

Comment: Also, thanks for the info on the charger and battery, Buscar.

Comment: The Current Capacity which increases as the battery charges is the number that topped 8000, thoiugh last night it just went to a couple hundred higher than the "Max Capacity" on Coconut. I am at work but when I get to my laptop I will post the screenshot.

Comment: What is the ohmic resistance issue that may be occuring? Can you explain what that means please?

Comment: see this http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_measure_internal_resistance but I think it is your coconutbattery doing it, it gets its information from the mac hardware and EFI, than it uses its software to show you results. For example it is physically not possible to charge a battery beyond its capacity (if you force it it would blowup), so your readings from coconut are WRONG.

Comment: Although,the Power link on "About this Mac" does show a "Current Capacity" as the same as Coconut. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Lets reset: you say the Battery is marked as 6100mah, but both coconut and about this mac show 8000mah?

Comment: On Coconut Battery there is a "Current Charge" and a "Maximum Charge"  When fully charged the Current is greater than the Maximum. It matches "charge Remaining" in About this Mac,

Comment: Is your replacement battery an Apple original part (installed by Apple or and Authorized Service Provider)?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that your computer shuts down at 50% remaining charge and also that your MagSafe LED remains orange makes me think that either the replacement battery isn't an official Apple part, that it is defective/DOA, or that your logic boards SMC is corrupted and needs to be reset.

If the battery is indeed new and Apple original than proceed with an SMC reset:

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3964

This will tell the SMC chip to reset all power states and reboot so that it forgets the battery and MagSafe adapter momentarily and then rediscovers them.

Hope that helps